# Отрисовка AnimationDrawable посредством Canvas

Tags: livewallpaper, canvas, java, android

Имеется ли возможность отрисовки объекта с заготовленной покадровой анимацией - `AnimationDrawable` на объекте `Bitmap`, посредством `Canvas`'а. В данном случае я бы хотел отрисовывать уже заготовленную анимацию на поверхности (Surface) объекта класса `LiveWallpaper`. То есть, хотел бы с минимумом кода отрисовывать что-то "живое" на "живых" обоях (специальный новый класс `LiveWallpaper`, появился в Android с версии 2.3)

Answer (score 1):

`AnimationDrawable` как и любой другой `Drawable` умеет себя [рисовать сам](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)).

```
animationDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

Или вы уже пробовали и не получилось?

Comment: Простите дурака. Поспешил с вопросом. Решил сразу обратиться за помощью. Вам спасибо и с наступающим новым годом.

Comment: @zugzug И вас с наступающим :)

Comment: Здравствуйте. Опробовал этот метод. Но он не работает в данном случае. Делом в том, что для отрисовки на живых обоях классом SurfaceHolder предоставляется Canvas на некоторое время для отрисовки, то есть он адаптирован для работы рисования из потока (Thread). AnimationDrawable и Thread вещи разные. Есть ли все таки схема использования в таком случае заготовленной анимации, т.е. задействовать в живых обоях класс AnimationDrawable?

Comment: @zugzug, как вы решили проблему?

Comment: @IvanVovk Здравстуйте. Простите, сейчас уже не вспомню. Давно отошёл от разработки под Андроид и те исходники вероятнее всего уже потеряны.